# Is elementaryOS 5.1 "Hera" supported on Intel 10th Gen Mobile Processors?

Tags: release-hera, kernel, laptop, intel

I want to try out elementaryOS on my new laptop. But it is very new, and I don't think the kernel included in Ubuntu 18.04 (v5.3) supports its processor (Intel Core i3-1005G1). Is it true? Does elementaryOS v5.1 support the Ice Lake Processors of Intel?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu backports newer Linux kernels through its [hardware-enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).
This means that older releases of Ubuntu, and elementary OS by extension, can run on newer hardware.

That said, a [query](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=cpu:intel-6-126-5-core-i3-1005g1) for your CPU on [linux-hardware.com](https://linux-hardware.org/) shows that plenty of Linux distributions have been running on it successfully and there is even an Ubuntu 18.04 in the list, on which the latest release of elementary OS is based.
In other words, it should definitely work.

Booting the elementary OS installer on the system via USB is also a good test.
If it can boot and appears to work well, that typically means things will work barring the troubles stemming from third-party drivers and buggy firmware and all that.

Comment: I saw that a person on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198773/ubuntu-18-04-with-intel-10th-gen-graphics-cant-change-color-profiles) tried to run 18.04 on a CPU older than mine, and he was experiencing issues. Also, the query which you shared had the processor in a tablet. So, I can't be sure if it works or not. Maybe I'll have to check it out with a live USB then

Comment: You're definitely right about that. Most of those probes are running pretty recent kernels, too. I managed to find one on Ubuntu 20.04 but using the 5.4 kernel on a laptop [here](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=d1bdd46e5a). My elementary OS 5.1 machine uses the 5.4 kernel at the moment.

Comment: The processor and GPU is the same in the one you mentioned. If elementaryOS 5.1 really has kernel 5.4, then I am sure it can run the processor and GPU